# Retrieving client IP address in a microservice application with Ocelot gateway

Tags: .net, ip, ocelot

I have a microservice application consisting of three microservices:

Gateway using Ocelot
Identity microservice
Core API microservice
However, when I try to retrieve the client's IP address from the Core API, while passing through the gateway, I receive "(::1)" instead of the actual IP address.

```
  public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _context; 

    public IdentityService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }
  
    public string GetCleintAdressIP()
    {
        string clientIpAddress = $"({_context?.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() ?? "unknown"})";
        return clientIpAddress;
    }
}
```

How can I correctly obtain the client's IP address in this setup?

Please note any relevant code/configuration snippets and error messages to help diagnose the issue.