# Keep client's IP in http header in Ocelot

Tags: .net, http, ocelot

Similar to this question which has no answer:
[Retrieving client IP address in a microservice application with Ocelot gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983626/retrieving-client-ip-address-in-a-microservice-application-with-ocelot-gateway)

My project is in .NET 7 and made by Ocelot library (latest version) to hide microservice's paths from the client and I need to keep client's IP in requests, now IP of Ocelot project is in http requests not clients.

I want to keep client's IP in headers like host, referrer and origin (any of them would be enough). So, for the first solution I added a middleware to my code:

```cs
    public class IPWriter: IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var clientIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp))
            {
                // Overwrite the Host header with the client's IP
                context.Request.Host = new HostString(clientIp);
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, didn't work. I added middleware as Singleton to services in different places (as first middleware, as middle and as last one).

And I know I can add a config to my project:

```json
"AddHeadersToRequest": {
  "X-Forwarded-For": "true"
}
```

It puts client's IP in a header named X-Forwarded-For, but I want it to be in the headers I've mentioned.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In an Ocelot .NET 7 core project, for adding client's IP to headers of request when it gets to its destination, add this to config:

```json
      "UpstreamHeaderTransform": {
        "Referrer": "{RemoteIpAddress}",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "{RemoteIpAddress}",
      },
```